# Different picture format - Image Viewer - WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I got pictures in the isolated storage and i want to display them as well as the WINDOWS PHONE APP does. 
I would like to reproduce the same effect that the Windows phone app does when you open the camera roll and you scroll through the images..

I find it particularly difficult because of the image orientation  (horizontal and the vertical ones). I fit the vertical ones, but as soon as there are an horizontal picture any fit procedure fails!

Example?

thank you

Comment: Posting some sample code/xaml might help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MediaViewer class in the Silverlight Basic Lens sample. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Lens-sample-359fda1b